# Extend class, define function parameter in subclass body? super constructor cannot be passed a self reference unless parameter is declared by-name

Tags: scala

1) Consider the following example:

```
trait Fuel
trait Flow extends Fuel
trait Gas extends Fuel

trait CarbonDioxide

abstract class Car[I, O](engine: I => O) {
  def run(fuel: Fuel): O = {
    engine(fuel)
  }
}

object Electric extends Car[Flow, Unit]((flow: Flow) => ())
object Petrol extends Car[Gas, CarbonDioxide]((gas: Gas) => new CarbonDioxide {})
```

Instead of declaring the `engine: I => O` function directly in the constructor I would prefer to define a (more complex) method in the body of `Petrol`, like so:

```
object Petrol extends Car[Gas, CarbonDioxide](Petrol.run) {

  def run(gas: Gas): CarbonDioxide =
  {
    new CarbonDioxide {}
  }
}
```

Now this looks okay in my IDE but the compiler says:

> super constructor cannot be passed a self reference unless parameter is declared by-name

How can I overcome this?

2) If somewhere in my code I do this:

```
val fuelCars = Map(
  "Flow" -> Electric,
  "Gas" -> Petrol
)

println(fuelCars("Flow").run(new Flow{})
```

The code

`object Petrol extends Car[Gas, CarbonDioxide]((gas: Gas) => new CarbonDioxide {})` works, but as soon as I change it to the second variant with `run` I get

> Cannot resolve reference run with such signature

But why?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't make an abstract method in `Car` like `def engine:(in: I): O`?

Comment: Yes, that code is already there from a third party and I have to extend it :(

Comment: wrt #2, `fuelCars("Flow")` is not going to be the type you want. It cannot infer that it takes a `Flow` as `Fuel`.

Answer (score 1):

The super-class is constructed before the sub-class so you can't pass a constructor parameter to the super from the sub that hasn't been constructed yet.

Perhaps the best you can do is supply dummy code for the `engine` argument (which is private and can't be overridden) and then override any/all code that references the `engine` argument.

```
abstract class Car[I, O](engine: I => O) {
  def run(fuel: I): O = engine(fuel)
}

object Petrol extends Car[Gas, CarbonDioxide](_ => new CarbonDioxide{}) {
                           // dummy code here ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^//
  override def run(gas: Gas): CarbonDioxide = {/* real replacement code here*/}
}
```